# Using dd to back up only contents an image on an SD card

Tags: dd

I have a Raspberry Pi (RPi) with a 128 GB SD card. This SD card contains the full OS and settings for the RPi and I would like to back it up. The total size of all files on the SD card are around 350 MB.

I put the SD card into my laptop which runs a Linux distro and used dd to make a copy of the *contents* of the SD card:

```bash
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=RPi4Image.img
```

This command was taking a long time and I checked the file size being generated on my laptop and it was in the 44 GB size and not finished being created. I assume I would end up with a 128 GB file size, to only backup 350 MB of content, which is not useful to me.

I stopped the process.

It seems to me that this dd command makes an image of the whole SD card, all 128GB of it, even when I only need to backup the 350 MB of contents / files on it.

- Am I correct in assuming that the dd command backs up the whole device and so makes a file size that is equal to the whole SD card size?
- If so, are there any ways to backup, and be able to restore to an SD card, if needed, only the 350 MB of contents of the SD card?

Comment: 1. Do not, under any circumstances, backup the SD card with live partitions (i.e. one that's running your OS at the at moment)

Comment: 2. No need to use `dd`, just use `cat`, especially as you're not using any sensible flags for `dd`. For example, `sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/sdb >RPi4Image.img'`

Comment: 3. If you're using `cat` you can also use `gzip` (or `bzip2` or `xz`). For example, `sudo sh -c 'gzip </dev/sdb >RPi4Image.img.gz'`

Comment: @ChrisDavies thanks for taking the time to help me out :)

Comment: FYI I've only commented rather than providing an answer because I didn't answer the question you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that the dd command backs up the whole device and so makes a file size that is equal to the whole SD card size?

Yes, `dd` does a block-by-block copy

> If so, are there any ways to backup, and be able to restore to an SD card, if needed, only the 350 MB of contents of the SD card?

You can use [Partclone](https://partclone.org/) to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

`dd` without arguments copies from source to destination until reaching the end of one or the other, but it is not the only way of using the tool, or even the usual.
If, for example you know that the filesystem on the card was limited to the first 2GB of space you could specify to only dump that much. You do this using the `bs` blocksize option and the `count` option.

```bash
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=new.img bs=1M count=2048
```

If necessary you could maybe use `resize2fs` to resize a linux filesystem to make it occupy only the beginning of the drive.

If however, the filesystem was not limited to part of the disk, and isn't a filesystem you can resize from Linux like ext2/3/4 then your only option is to take an image of the entire disk/partition.

Fortunately, if your system was put on a fresh card and you weren't using it read-write for a long time this system will usually have a **LOT** or zeros and will compress down to almost exactly the used space. So gzip or zip the image file as soon as you have it.

You can even do this on the fly so that you never need the whole file on the disk:

```bash
dd if=/dev/sdb1 | gzip | dd of=new.img.gz
```

This is because if `if` or `of` aren't specified they default to `stdin` or `stdout`. It won't save on copy time but will save on disk space needed to store the image.